# collection copy behavior question

Tags: c#, .net

in c#, after I add a object to a collection, if another copy(deep copy) is always created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if it is a class, most objects are, only a reference to the same object is stored in the collection.

If it is a value type, like int, double and structs a copy is made (not a deep copy, if the struct has a reference to a class object that in turn will not be copied).

**Edit:**
To deep copy objects you first need to create a deep copy function.
Have a look at [Create a Deep Copy in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647048/create-a-deep-copy-in-c) or [How to make a deep copy in C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054075/how-to-make-a-deep-copy-in-c)
Then you can run your deep copy method before adding items to your collection.

**Note**
It is not very often you really need a true deep copy. Often it is better to rethink the dataflow in your application.

Comment: Then how to have a deep copied collection?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about what happens with the collection, then it depends:

Normally, a collection will be created with some "empty" slots, so adding to it will not cause a new collection with a new size to be created.

If, however adding a new item goes beyond this size, a new collection will be created and all items copied to it.

---

If you are asking about the item itself, again it depends:

If it is a value type (int, double, structs for example), then the value will be copied, if it is a reference type, a copy of the reference to the same object will be used.