# Converting object of a class to of another one

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I have two classes which have are nearly equal except the data types stored in them. One class contains all double values while other contains all float values.

```
class DoubleClass
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
}

class FloatClass
{
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
}
```

Now I have a point of DoubleClass which I want to convert to FloatClass.

```
var doubleObject = new DoubleClass();

var convertedObject = (FloatClass)doubleObject; // TODO: This
```

One simple way is to make a method which creates a new FloatClass object, fills all values and return it. Is there any other efficient way to do this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263099/function-to-clone-an-arbitrary-object

Comment: Are you allowed to change the source code for FloatClass and/or DoubleClass?

Comment: @I4V Conversion != Cloning

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Use a conversion operator:**

```
public static explicit operator FloatClass (DoubleClass c) {
   FloatCass fc = new FloatClass();
   fc.X = (float) c.X;
   fc.Y = (float) c.Y;
   fc.Z = (float) c.Z;
   return fc;
}
```

And then just use it:

```
var convertedObject = (FloatClass) doubleObject;
```

**Edit**

I changed the operator to `explicit` instead of `implicit` since I was using a `FloatClass` cast in the example. I prefer to use `explicit` over `implicit` so it forces me to confirm what type the object will be converted to *(to me it means less distraction errors + readability).*

However, you can use `implicit` conversion and then you would just need to do:

```
var convertedObject = doubleObject;
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Comment: You need to cast the doubles to floats to avoid a compile error.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yap. Good eye. Thanks

Comment: Now I want to convert a 2D array of DoubleClass to FloatClass, is it possible using LINQ? or I have to use for loops here?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez you can try: `FloatClass[] converted = Array.ConvertAll(array, s => (FloatClass) s);` for simple arrays or see this implementation for 2D arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065947/1873446

Comment: @letiagoalves: You can even omit the cast operator if you have an implicit cast: `FloatClass fc = doubleObject;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know that but I prefer to do so. I don't mind the extra characters because it is more readable to me :)

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you could use generics here:

```
 public class GenericClass<T>
 {
    T X { get; set; }
    T Y { get; set; }
    T Z { get; set; }
 }

 GenericClass<float> floatClass = new GenericClass<float>();
 GenericClass<double> doubleClass = new GenericClass<double>();
```

Comment: It can be a solution, but code is being used in many places, so this solution will require much effort,

Comment: CTRL+F -> "FloatClass" -> V (Expand) -> "GenericClass<float>" -> Replace All. Done :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Conversion Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx)  to achieve this.

Fr example:

```
struct FloatClass
{
    public FloatClass(DoubleClass dClass) {
        //conversion...
    }
    ... 
    public static explicit operator FloatClass(DoubleClass dClass) 
    {
        FloatClassd = new FloatClass(dClass);  // explicit conversion

        return d;
    }
}


var convertedObject = (FloatClass)doubleObject;
```

Comment: Now I want to convert a 2D array of DoubleClass to FloatClass, is it possible using LINQ? or I have to use for loops here?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: you can, for example,  add an [ExtensionMethds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for your array class.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an [implicit  type conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx):

```
public class DoubleClass
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public static implicit operator FloatClass(DoubleClass d)
    {
        return new FloatClass { X = (float)d.X, Y = (float)d.Y, Z = (float)d.Z };
    }
}
```

Now this works:

```
DoubleClass doubleObject = new DoubleClass();
FloatClass convertedObject = doubleObject;
```

Comment: Now I want to convert a 2D array of DoubleClass to FloatClass, is it possible using LINQ? or I have to use for loops here?

Answer (score 2):

Add a class for thease extention methods :

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this Object fromObject)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fromObject));
    }


    public static List<T> ToObjectList<T>(this Object fromObject)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fromObject));
    }
}
```

Use :

```
using YourExtentionMethodNamespace;

Class2 obj2 = obj1.ToObject<Class2>();
List<Class2> lst2 = _db.Blogs.ToList().ToObjectList<Class2>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by using serializer. Use Newtonsoft JSON serializer which works best.

using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
  private void Convert()
    {
        DoubleClass doubleClass = new DoubleClass {X = 123.123, Y = 321.321, Z = 111.111};
        var serializedoubleClass = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doubleClass);
        var floatClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedoubleClass, typeof(FloatClass));
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to convert objects

Answer (score 0):

**Best way for Convert**

```
public static class Extention {
     public static string ConvertObjectToJson(this object ob)
     {
         return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ob);
     }
}
```

**For Usage**

```
var doubleClass = new DoubleClass {
   x = 10,
   y = 20
};
var floatClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FloatClass>(doubleClass.ConvertObjectToJson());
```

Answer (score -3):

Best way is Serialize object and again desalinize it

Comment: The deserialization will fail because the structures are not equivalent in their storage mechanisms.  Even if they were, and it could work, it would still be prohibitively expensive and a fairly poor practice to do this.

Comment: of course, because when you conver it, probably would be very salty, that's why you need to desalinize it after, jk